# DateTime picker refuses to display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, datetimepicker

Hi I am new to MVC and I have an input box where a user must enter a date. For some reason my date time picker is not displaying and I have to manually type in the date. I have declared all script files in my layout page. Am I missing something?

This is my display

[image]

This is my code for my view

```
          <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.order_preffered_date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">

                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.order_preffered_date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })


                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.order_preffered_date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Is this the entirety of the view code? Usually there is some jquery $('datepicker').datepicker(); code in the page (or in the master).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you have an editor template set up for whatever type model.order_preffered_date is (DateTime probably) - Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTime.cshtml - that contains your datepicker markup?

(BTW it's 'preferred', not 'preffered' - sorry to be pedantic but Thrupps will thank you :) )

Follow-up: If you don't want to use a specific editor template of your own, then ensure it's removed (so the default is used) and then the following checklist should sort you out:

1. Bootstrap datepicker CSS & JS file declared on the page (you've already mentioned you've done this - I assume jQuery is already present)
2. The datepicker element is initialised in the document.ready function somewhere, e.g.

   ```
   $(function() {
     ...
     $('.datepicker').datepicker();
     ...
   });
   ```
3. If this is still not helping, then ensure your model property is decorated appropriately with DataType:

   ```
   [DataType(DataType.Date)]
   public DateTime order_preffered_date {get;set;}
   ```

Comment: I have added the editor template but still no date time picker :(

Comment: Hi where do I find the CSS and JS file for point 1 and point 2 where do I get the code for this?